# MYSQL Read-only DB in memory optimization

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I've created a website for biochem researchers that allows users to query specific genes and calculate various statistics between different sets of genes.

The MySQL DB is 16GB and read-only (our lab generated this novel data and the website is a portal to view this data) . I've performance tested the website and realized that the DB query is the slowest portion of the app. I want to put the entire DB into memory but ran into a few problems with the generally accepted solutions:

I have an 8-core 32GB server for use.

**Option 1: set ENGINE = MEMORY**

A few columns are of type `mediumtext` and exceed the 64k row limit and refuse to be put into the `MEMORY ENGINE`

**Option 2: increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size`**

This doesn't seem to actually put the data into memory. I checked the used buffer pool using the techniques described (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size) but only see ~100Mbs of used buffer pool. The `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is correctly set to 24GB.

**Option 3: Create a RAMdisk and put the DB on there**
This doesn't seem like a great option based on a few SO posts.

How should I continue? Please advise.

Comment: If every Query is OK ? Use all queries a optimal index ? can you tell a little bit more about the tables an rows

Comment: The buffer is only filled over time while the db is used. Did you actually let it run for a while, under varying load?

Comment: Buffer pool doesn't get filled if you don't *use* the data you work with. Once you use it, MySQL reads it from the disk and adds it to buffer pool (RAM), so the next time you deal with it - it's there. There's a trick you can use to preload buffer pool by creating a temporary blackhole table and load it with data: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE preload ENGINE   = BLACKHOLE  SELECT * FROM table_to_preload_into_buffer_pool`. I'm not aware if there's any sort of config option that lets you preload this on startup, but this should help you to preload the buffer pool.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check EXPLAIN and profiling ?

**sample for profiling**

here you can see where your server spends the time and optimize this

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> set profiling=on;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]> select * from table2 t1 left join table2 t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id;;
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
| id     | val        | id     | val        |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
| 000002 | tabe 2 --2 | 000001 | tabe 2 --1 |
....
| 000005 | tabe 2 --5 | 000004 | tabe 2 --4 |
| 000006 | tabe 2 --6 | 000004 | tabe 2 --4 |
| 000001 | tabe 2 --1 | 000005 | tabe 2 --5 |
| 000002 | tabe 2 --2 | 000005 | tabe 2 --5 |
| 000004 | tabe 2 --4 | 000005 | tabe 2 --5 |
| 000006 | tabe 2 --6 | 000005 | tabe 2 --5 |
| 000001 | tabe 2 --1 | 000006 | tabe 2 --6 |
| 000002 | tabe 2 --2 | 000006 | tabe 2 --6 |
| 000004 | tabe 2 --4 | 000006 | tabe 2 --6 |
| 000005 | tabe 2 --5 | 000006 | tabe 2 --6 |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [yourschema]> show profile all;
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
| Status               | Duration | CPU_user | CPU_system | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Messages_sent | Messages_received | Page_faults_major | Page_faults_minor | Swaps | Source_function       | Source_file   | Source_line |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
| starting             | 0.000113 | 0.000072 |   0.000041 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 2 |     0 | NULL                  | NULL          |        NULL |
| checking permissions | 0.000006 | 0.000003 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | check_access          | sql_parse.cc  |        6051 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 | 0.000004 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | check_access          | sql_parse.cc  |        6051 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000307 | 0.000071 |   0.000236 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 9 |     0 | open_tables           | sql_base.cc   |        4509 |
| After opening tables | 0.000010 | 0.000006 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | open_tables           | sql_base.cc   |        4747 |
| System lock          | 0.000005 | 0.000004 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc       |         308 |
| Table lock           | 0.000010 | 0.000009 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc       |         313 |
| init                 | 0.000027 | 0.000025 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_select          | sql_select.cc |        3427 |
| optimizing           | 0.000014 | 0.000012 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize_inner        | sql_select.cc |        1092 |
| statistics           | 0.000022 | 0.000021 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize_inner        | sql_select.cc |        1373 |
| preparing            | 0.000117 | 0.000037 |   0.000084 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 4 |     0 | optimize_inner        | sql_select.cc |        1398 |
| executing            | 0.000010 | 0.000004 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | exec_inner            | sql_select.cc |        2551 |
| Sending data         | 0.000106 | 0.000102 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | exec_inner            | sql_select.cc |        3223 |
| end                  | 0.000007 | 0.000004 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_select          | sql_select.cc |        3462 |
| query end            | 0.000008 | 0.000006 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc  |        5687 |
| closing tables       | 0.000004 | 0.000003 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | close_thread_tables   | sql_base.cc   |         935 |
| Unlocking tables     | 0.000008 | 0.000007 |   0.000001 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_unlock_tables   | lock.cc       |         395 |
| freeing items        | 0.000008 | 0.000006 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_parse           | sql_parse.cc  |        7319 |
| updating status      | 0.000023 | 0.000008 |   0.000015 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             1 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | dispatch_command      | sql_parse.cc  |        1937 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000004 | 0.000002 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | dispatch_command      | sql_parse.cc  |        1956 |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```